# Promoting widgets and using them from generated ui

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qt-designer

I am trying to create a custom widget by promoting it in Qt Designer. The problem is, Qt Designer automatically prepends `Ui_` to widget names. This leads to error in code generated for MainWindow:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'promotedWidget'
```

I can fix this error by renaming the widget (prepending `Ui_`) in Qt Designer, while promoting. But then, I get this error:

```
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

I got around this error by creating a new Python file that just wraps around `promotedWidget`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from promotedwidget_raw import Ui_promotedWidget

class Ui_promotedWidget(Ui_promotedWidget, QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def setupUi(self, promotedWidget):
        super().setupUi(promotedWidget)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    promotedWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_promotedWidget()
    ui.setupUi(promotedWidget)
    promotedWidget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This fixes the problem, but I don't like the idea of creating a wrapper just to get custom widget to work. (And I am pretty sure I'm doing it wrong)

Here are my (example) project files:

```
main.py
main_gui.pyw # Generated from ui
main_gui.ui
promotedwidget.pyw # Generated from ui
promotedwidget.ui
```

---

main.py:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from main_gui import Ui_MainWindow as MainWindow

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)

MainWindow.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

main_gui.pyw:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'main_gui.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.8.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.widget = promotedWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.widget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

from promotedwidget import promotedWidget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

promotedwidget.pyw:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'promotedwidget.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.8.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_promotedWidget(object):
    def setupUi(self, promotedWidget):
        promotedWidget.setObjectName("promotedWidget")
        promotedWidget.resize(400, 300)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(promotedWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(promotedWidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(promotedWidget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(promotedWidget)

    def retranslateUi(self, promotedWidget):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        promotedWidget.setWindowTitle(_translate("promotedWidget", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("promotedWidget", "Test"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    promotedWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_promotedWidget()
    ui.setupUi(promotedWidget)
    promotedWidget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have searched for how to make custom widgets with PyQt and Qt Designer, but I couldn't find an answer that matches my needs. Or I just couldn't wrap my head around the process yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt Designer provides the design class, does not provide a widget, we have the duty to implement widget and use the design, in your case the solution is simple, create the `promotedWidget` class and implement the design through the `setupUi()` function as I show below:

**promotedwidget.pyw:**

```
class Ui_promotedWidget(object):
    def setupUi(self, promotedWidget):
        [...]
    def retranslateUi(self, promotedWidget):
        [...]

class promotedWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_promotedWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```